# Ionic Deploy only works on my phone

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic2 app working fine with ionic deploy on my phone. I make ionic upload and deploy the new version, and my phone app upgrades itself to the last version.

The strange behaviour is that it does not work in the other Android smartphones that also have the app installed, and I do not know what is causing it.

Have you ever faced a problem like this? One phone works, all the others don't.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

When I install any old version of the app in any phone, the first time it enters the app, it install the last version. That is OK. But if later I upload a new version, my phone installs it, and the other phones don't.

Comment: did you enable usb debugging on the other phone? What happens when you plug other phone and deploy? Any errors?

Comment: I have not tested it, because it is supposed that it should deploy in every user phone, and that I have not to access to all those phones, isn't it? Or shoud I access to every phone that install the APP and enable USB debugging?